# bootstrap affix bottom not smooth in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I got problem about bootstrap affix-bottom on this code : http://jsfiddle.net/uvnGP/131/

```
var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true);
var footerHeight = $('footer').innerHeight();
$('#account-overview-container').affix({
    offset: {
    top: headerHeight,
    bottom: footerHeight
    }
}).on('affix.bs.affix', function () { // before affix
    $(this).css({
        'width': $(this).outerWidth()  // variable widths
    });
}).on('affix-bottom.bs.affix', function () { // before affix-bottom
    $(this).css('bottom', 'auto'); // THIS is what makes the jumping
});
```

when scroll on jsfiddle is smooth but once I tested the code on local (using Firefox), it's not smooth at all (sometime I scroll around footer and it show nav on the footer, pls check this screen capture http://awesomescreenshot.com/04e2gnjk17 ). I checked with firebug it shows that the nav class **change between affix and affix-bottom** when scroll at footer (it should be show stick on affix-bottom if scroll at footer).

how can i solve this problem ?

Thanks
Chalat

Comment: can you try it with firefox on safe mode? just to make sure it's not an addon's fault, do u test both local and online using the same browser?

Comment: oh.. when i uploaded my code into server and checked it run smooth :) so it only has problem when run offline. Thanks for ur help!!

Comment: make sure that you don't get any 404's locally from js or css files from the browser console